# How to refresh bing map?

Tags: php, jquery, bing-maps, bing

The bing map works fine if I refresh the page and push the pin. But if I do a ajax call and load the map, the previous pins stay. How to remove those pins?

Comment: i cant not use remove and removeAt as i have lost reference to the previous pins plotted.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using the AJAX v7 control, in order to remove previous items on the map, you can use the clear() method available in the EntityCollection class.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427616.aspx

So if you're using the basic way, you can use:

```
map.entities.clear();
```

I would recommand that you're using the iSDK to start with the API: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7